# DMLC and concurrent consumers working

Tags: activemq-classic, messaging, spring-jms

Does DMLC creates separate threads for each concurrent consumer? What happens under the hood? The documentation writes this:

> Actual MessageListener execution happens in asynchronous work units which are created through Spring's TaskExecutor abstraction. By default, the specified number of invoker tasks will be created on startup, according to the "concurrentConsumers" setting.

I am not able to understand this, are these tasks executed in parallel? If yes, what are the default limits for this, like thread count etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes a separate thread is used for each consumer (obtained from the task executor). By default, a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is used and the thread is destroyed when the consumer is stopped. There is no thread limit beyond the container's concurrency settings.

If you inject a different kind of task executor (such as a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`) you must make sure it has enough available threads to support your container's concurrency settings. Container threads are generally long-lived.